# Javascript syntax function error - Expected ')'

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, syntax

I am parsing a JSON object and want to make each object as a link and having them be able to call a function when clicked. I then append each of my objects to an unordered list. However, I am getting a syntax error in my code, but I think that the string is built properly. The error states JAVASCRIPT ERROR(unknown source) expected ')'

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
var string = "<a onclick=AppendDescription(" + obj[i].Name + ")>" + obj[i].Name + "</a>";
//This is what the string looks like after I build it. "<a onclick=AppendDescription(Test 1)>Test 1</a>"

$("#textbox ul").append("<li>"
        + string //error occurs here
        + "</li>");
```

Comment: I do not see any error messages related to that line - http://jsfiddle.net/mso7ssz6/, but if `obj[i].Name` has spaces or letters - it could create a problem due to the absence of quotes around the argument of the js function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier and better practice to attach event handlers in javascript rather than as HTML attributes.

I would do something like this :

```
$("<li/>").append($('<a href=""></a>').text(obj[i].Name).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    AppendDescription($(this).text());
})).appendTo("#textbox ul");
```

**Edit**

Even better, delegate the click handling to the parent UL.

```
$("#textbox ul").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    AppendDescription($(this).text());
})

for (var i=0; ...) {
    $("<li/>").append($('<a href=""></a>').text(obj[i].Name)).appendTo("#textbox ul");
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot. I'll keep this in mind next time I have a function like this.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some quotes. Try this

```
var string = "<a onclick=\"AppendDescription(\"" + obj[i].Name + "\")\">" + obj[i].Name + "</a>";
```

Comment: The function itself doesn't need to be in quotes, but its parameter  (obj[i].Name) does.

Comment: I got a syntax error from this one. It didn't come up with the missing ')' this time though.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting nailed by ASI. The parser is inserting a semi-colon at the end of that line. Move your concatenating `+` operator to the end of the line.

```
$("#textbox ul").append("<li>" +
    string +
    "</li>");
```

Comment: Ah, got the same error.

Comment: Damare's answer already covered the other problem, I should have mentioned that in mine.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript), it appears that javascript can't understand multiline without you saying that the string will continue on the next line.  It adds an semi-colon at the end like `$("#textbox ul").append("<li>";` so he thinks that you are missing an ')'

Answer (score 0):

Unless `obj[i].Name` is a number, it needs to be within quotes:

```
var string = "<a onclick=AppendDescription('" + obj[i].Name + "')>" + obj[i].Name + "</a>";
```

Comment: This one gets me - Unterminated String Constant.

Comment: It could fail if `obj[i].Name` contains quotes.  Anyway, @Roamer-1888 has the best answer.